# Outer space battles in Mahabharatha?

Tags: mahabharata, reference-request

I came across [this](http://www.infinityfoundation.com/Jedi.htm) article by Steven J. Rosen on the inspiration from Hindu itihasas for the Star Wars series. The following claim caught my attention:

> Arjuna, too, in the Mahabharata, is said to engage in many battles while in outer space.

It is well known that Vimana battles find frequent mention in the Puranas, but is it mentioned anywhere that Arjuna fought in outer space? I am assuming it is a vague reference to other Lokas rather than outer space.

Comment: Not just Arjuna, many mighty emperors , Rakshasas invaded heaven and hell which are different lokas and cannot be reached normally with this material body, though it is within the material creation as per hinduism. So, in that sense one may say there were outer space wars.

Comment: @Krishna some interpretations say that the lokas are in this plane of existence. Other interpretations say that the lokas exist on different 'vibrational' planes of existence - not on the material plane.

Comment: @Swami Vishwananda - Well, they may exist in this plane or on different plane, heaven and hell per se are within material plane, because Sruti clearly indicates that Jiva's stay in heaven or hell is only to the extent of his or her good or bad karma. Once, those are exhausted, one gets into cycle of birth and death again. When I said material, i meant to convey these higher lokas ( Indra loka alias heaven and other lokas which are not permanent)

Comment: @krishna No. Sruti does not say that the lokas are on the material plane. Sruti is silent on this point. You need to remember that the what goes to the lokas is the subtle body, which has no existence on the material plane.

Comment: @Swami Vishwananda - I do remember reading somewhere, that a king who reached heaven, and he saw, an apsara pushing a jiva from heaven downwards. When enquired the king was told that his turn will also come. I don't remember the source....So, in that sense heaven is within material realm as one to come back from heaven and get caught in the cycle of birth and death.

Comment: @Krishna The return path is described in Chandogya Upanishad V. x. 5-6. Saying an aspara is pushing you down is a poetical way of saying it.

Comment: @Swami Viswananda - So, Vedanta which is also sruti, does say that heaven etc are ephemeral and not permanent. But, you said Sruti is silent about it. Even advaitins accept that Upanishads are part of Sruti only or you think, Vedanta is not part of Sruti. Whether it is poetical way or other way, Sruti does say that Heaven etc are not permanent.

Comment: @krishna where does it say? Which Upanishad? Which Veda? What verses?....Please tell me. If you don't know exactly where do not say that it does...

Comment: @Swami Vishwananda - You yourself quoted the Chandogya Upanishad, regarding return path. So, it is very clear there is heaven which is temporary. Again, you say Sruti is silent. Please provide the proof. You are contradicting yourself as usual.